# PySpark mapPartitions resulting in Py4JJavaError

Tags: pyspark, py4j

I am trying to run a code which I have not written. The description of the code says that this is a way to convert spark dataframe to a pandas dataframe in a speedy way and was borrowed from [here](https://gist.github.com/joshlk/871d58e01417478176e7).

```
def to_pandas(df: pyspark.sql.DataFrame, n_partitions: Optional[int] = None) -> pd.DataFrame:
   
    :param df: Spark DataFrame to be transformed to a Pandas DataFrame
    :param n_partitions: The target number of partitions
    :return: The Pandas DataFrame version of the provided ``df``
   
    if n_partitions is not None:
        df = df.repartition(n_partitions)

    df_pandas = df.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda rdds: [pd.DataFrame(list(rdds))]).collect()
    df_pandas = pd.concat(df_pandas, ignore_index=True)
    df_pandas.columns = df.columns

    return df_pandas
```

However, running this gives a Py4J error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dbconnect\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 967, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dbconnect\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dbconnect\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 117, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\dbconnect\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1698)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor313.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor313.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor313.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:488)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor313.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2093)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1655)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ProtoSerializer.$anonfun$deserializeObject$1(ProtoSerializer.scala:6631)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.util.ProtoSerializer.deserializeObject(ProtoSerializer.scala:6616)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.execute0(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:728)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.$anonfun$executeRPC0$1(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:477)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.executeRPC0(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:372)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler$$anon$2.call(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:323)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler$$anon$2.call(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.$anonfun$executeRPC$1(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:359)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCHandler.executeRPC(SparkServiceRPCHandler.scala:336)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCServlet.doPost(SparkServiceRPCServer.scala:167)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What does this mean and how can it be circumvented? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same "Invalid type code: 00" error from Pyspark.  I was using databricks-connect version 9.1.10 which was breaking and to fix the problem I updated to the latest 9.1.* version (9.1.21) which fixed the issue.  Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I know, the problem in the question is `Py4JJavaError`; but the need for this approach seems to be Spark to Pandas dataframe conversion.

In my experience, this type of conversion is subject to volume of the data. Also, `pd.concat()` may result in `OutOfMemory` error, if data size exceeds the limit, which driver can handle.

You should try multiple approaches and a do a volume v/s time comparison for each method.

The method which I follow is:

- Export from Spark as parquet (CSV format accuracy is subject to proper handling of `,` in dataset)

```py
spark_df.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("dbfs:/my_dir")
```

- and then import in Pandas:

```py
pandas_df = pd.read_parquet(/"dbfs/my_dir/part-0xxxxxxx.parquet")
```

The exported parquet filename is based on partition and timestamp. Hence, I've written following utility function to make life easier:

```py
def export_spark_df_to_parquet(df, dir_dbfs_path, parquet_file_name):
  tmp_parquet_dir_name = "tmp"
  tmp_parquet_dir_dbfs_path = dir_dbfs_path + "/" + tmp_parquet_dir_name
  parquet_file_dbfs_path = dir_dbfs_path + "/" + parquet_file_name
  
  # Export dataframe to Parquet
  print("Exporting dataframe to Parquet...")
  df.repartition(1).write.mode("overwrite").parquet(tmp_parquet_dir_dbfs_path)
  listFiles = dbutils.fs.ls(tmp_parquet_dir_dbfs_path)
  for _file in listFiles:
    if len(_file.name) > len(".parquet") and _file.name[-len(".parquet"):] == ".parquet":
      print(f"Copying file {_file.path} to {parquet_file_dbfs_path}")
      dbutils.fs.cp(_file.path, parquet_file_dbfs_path)
      break
```

and use as:

```
export_spark_df_to_parquet(spark_df, "dbfs:/my_dir", "my_file.parquet")
```

Though, this answer does not directly address your problem; but can work for your dataframe conversion need.

Now, I can import from a fixed parquet file:

```py
pandas_df = pd.read_parquet(/"dbfs/my_dir/my_file.parquet")
```